# Generic type property

Tags: c#, generics

I have this class

```
public class Foo<T>
{
  ...
  public T Boo {get; set;}
}
```

Later I create new instance of class `Foo`,

```
public class Roo<TInput,TOutput>{
    public string DoThings(TInput param)
    {
        Foo<TInput> x = new Foo<TInput>{ ..., Boo = param};
        var y = x.Boo.Zoo;
    }
}
```

`Boo` has a property `Zoo`, but I can't see it, aka this doesn't work

```
var y = x.Boo.Zoo;
```

but I can see that `Zoo` is there during a debug, only `Equals,GetHashCode,ToString` and `GetType` are available.

The definition of a `Zoo` field is:

```
string Zoo;
```

How can I assign above `y`?

Comment: Please show us a complete code sample, without the `...`.  What are you providing as the type?  Where in your code are you trying to access that `Zoo` property?  Please edit your question with a [mre].

Comment: You generic type parameter `T` isn't restricted and can be any type and compiler doesn't know which properties/methods it has. Make sense to add generic type parameter

Comment: "Boo has a property Zoo" - Boo is just a name. It depends on the type `T` what properties it has.

Comment: @EricKlaus Show us the type definition for `TInput`.  Your code still isn't an [mre].

Comment: Does `TInput` defines  `Zoo` field? Is ti public?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn i don't know, TInput is within a class

Comment: Still no context on where you want to access Zoo

Comment: I mean I get that x.Boo  is generic and it can be anything, for specific part above, x.Boo has Zoo as a property when I do a debug. I wonder whether I can pull that Zoo

Comment: Can you show the definition of a `Zoo`?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Zoo is just a string

Comment: so it's defined as `string Zoo;` ??

Comment: @EricKlaus Originally you were making it look like `TInput` was the actual name of the final type that has `Zoo` as its property. Now you've revealed that `TInput` is yet another generic parameter, that is, can be any type. So it's not clear why you expect "any class" to have `string Zoo`.

Comment: @EricKlaus Please make a DotNetFiddle that reproduces this issue so we can follow along.  We still don't have a [mre].

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Implementing `ToString()` to return `Zoo` to the class which goes inside `param` worked

Comment: Now I'm very curious what was going on. You're using `ToString()` as a getter to get around access issues? *NOT good!*

Answer (score 2):

Code below works. And the generic class semantic is exact the same.

```cs
var x = new List<string> { "123" }

var y = x[0].Length; // x[0] - returns String, which is generic
```

However if you want to have "generic wrapper" it is better to extract interface. To return to your code:

```cs
interface IFoo 
{
     string Zoo { get; set; }
}

public class Roo<TInput,TOutput> where TInput: IFoo {
    public string QueueJob(TInput param)
    {
        Foo<TInput> x = new Foo<TInput>{ ..., Boo = param};

        return x.Boo.Zoo; // we require TInput to implement IFoo. It means that any input value have Zoo property, therefore you can use it
    }
}
```

Why do we need this interface (or base class):

- `TInput` can be any type. For example - `int`
- If you want to call specific method, you have to restrict input types. For example, you can require interface implementation.